# Angular JS: Call sequentially Async factory method

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angular, factory

I'm new to angular and I'm creating a simple search app. In my search app i am using factory where i have two function(Search and Demographic that call two different webapi to retrieve data as follow.

```
MYSearchApp.factory('dataProvider', function($http, $q,$timeout) {



    return {

        search: function (filter) {
            var dataUrl = '/api/xyz/search';
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.post(dataUrl, filter)
                .success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function (err,status) {
                    if (status == -1) {
                        err = "Server not responding";
                    }
                    deferred.reject(err);
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        },

        Demographics: function (filter) {
            var dataUrl = '/api/xyz/Demographics';
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.post(dataUrl, filter)
                .success(function (data) {

                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function (err,status) {
                    if (status == -1) {
                        err = "Server not responding";
                    }
                    deferred.reject(err);
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        }



    }
});
```

I am calling the function in my code as below:

```
MYSearchApp.controller('SearchController',
    function SearchController($scope, $route, $routeParams, dataProvider, consts, $timeout) {

.................
..............


$scope.search = function (searchForm) {


dataProvider.Demographics(filter).then(function(data)   {
                    if (data && data.length > 0) {

                        $scope.Email = data[0].Email;
                    }
                }

                )

dataProvider.search(filter).then(function (data) {

                    if (data && data.length > 0) {

            $scope.Details = data;

        })

        }

}
```

As of now both the function running at the same time, however i would like to know how i can run this function sequentially i.e. i want to execute demographics first and after the result received i would like to execute search method.

it would be great if someone can share some example how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: [Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426081/running-http-requests-sequentially-in-angularjs) it may help.

Comment: Are you using AngularJS 1.x (`angularjs`) or Angular 2 (`angular2`)?

Comment: I am using AngularJS 1.x